# Does a mdf implies the application's database is not embedded?

Tags: c#, wpf, mdf

I have installed an application and each file saved is .mdf. During installation of the software I have not seen any database being installed, and after installation I checked my program files and not SQL server or other database server being installed. I though the application would have an embedded database, but SQL Compact should only generate .sdf file, not .mdf file - what kind of embedded database sever would create .mdf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fair chance that [Sql Server Express User Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28SQL.90%29.aspx) are being used. Though if you're *sure* that you've checked both `Program Files` and `Program Files(x86)` and can't see any references to Sql Server then that can't be the case. That said, use the Services management console (Start > Services.msc) and look for services whose names start with "SQL Server" to verify that for definite.

One thing worth bearing in mind is that just because an application saves files with an extension of `.mdf` that doesn't mean that the files are Sql Server files. I could save a text file in notepad as `myfile.mdf`, but that still wouldn't make it a Sql Server file.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other editions of SQL use .mdf files. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx
Another way to check if some SQL database is running is checking your Services management console. even SQL express should have a service.